# Netbeans auto-complete XSL-FO

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, xsl-fo

Netbeans works fine in auto-completing XSLT.
Is there a way to make it auto-complete XSL-FO ?

I tried to add several DTD to the user catalog.

Tools > DTD and XML Schemas > User Catalog

Pointing System id to 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format'

But without success.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the W3C XML Schema for XSL-FO that is included in **focheck** releases.  See https://github.com/AntennaHouse/focheck

The schema in **focheck** is maintained as RELAX NG, but the releases include XSD files that are translated from the RELAX NG version.

Comment: Using this XSD Doesn't change anything.